# Python redmine: wiki page text

Tags: python, python-3.x, redmine

I use [python-redmine](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/python-redmine/) and want to get wiki page text, but get error - attribute isn't exists (but text exists), here is my code:

```
from redmine import Redmine

redmine = Redmine('http://redmine.example.com', username='user', password='1234')
projects = redmine.project.all()

for project in projects:
    print('Project: '+project.name)
    try:
        for page in project.wiki_pages:
            try:
                print('Title: '+page.title)
            except:
                print('Title: none')

            try:
                print('Content: '+page.text)
            except:
                print('Content: none')
            print('\n===========================\n')
    except:
        print('None')
```

How can I get text from wiki page? Help me pease!

pS: Python 3, python-redmine installed by pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a wiki page text this way because `project.wiki_pages` returns just a list of all wiki pages available for a project with a few other details. To get a text, author and some other info for a wiki page you have to make a separate call for each wiki page:

```
from redmine import Redmine

redmine = Redmine('http://redmine.example.com', username='user', password='1234')
projects = redmine.project.all()

for project in projects:
    print('Project: ' + project.name)

    for wiki_page in project.wiki_pages:
        wiki_page_details = redmine.wiki_page.get(wiki_page.title, project_id=project.id)

        print('Title: ' + wiki_page_details.title)
        print('Content: ' + wiki_page_details.text)
        print('\n===========================\n')
```

This is not very efficient but Python Redmine is just an interface to the Redmine REST API, and Redmine doesn't provide a way to get all information about project wiki pages in one call, so making a separate call for each wiki page is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Rails wraps attribute to methods so it is hard to say where you use attribute where it is just a method.

[Here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.4-stable/app/models/wiki_page.rb#L25) you can see that `wiki_page` has one content and [here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.4-stable/app/models/wiki_page.rb#L139) you can see method definition for `text` (attribute `text` belongs to content!).

I don't have experience to work with `python-redmine` but I can suppose that you need to call `page.content.text` not `page.text`. Or fetch `page.content` some other way.